# Create instance of 'Athlete' who is a 'Person'

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make the below code work so that I can create an instance of 'mary' who is an 'Athlete' who is a 'Person'. Can anybody point out what I am doing wrong here?

```
var Person = function(name, age, sex) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.sex = sex;
}

var Athlete = function(name, age, sex, sport) {
  this.prototype = new Person(name, age, sex);
  this.sport = sport;
}

Person.prototype.describe = function() {
  console.log('This is ' + this.name + ' and he is a ' + this.age + ' year old ' + this.sex + '.');
};

var john = new Person('John', 23, 'male');

var mary = new Athlete('Mary', 18, 'female', 'running');

john.describe();
mary.describe();
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: `this.prototype = new Person(name, age, sex);` is not what you want. I recommend to read [MDN - Inheritance in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) and [MDN - Introducing JavaScript objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects) in general.

Comment: That's  what I'm looking for, thanks Felix Kling.  I tried searching but couldn't put my problem into the correct words to return the result I needed!